# How to change display orientation in all devices of android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have written codes to create a camera with surfaceView. I have changed **screen Orientation in Portrait** using **androidManifest.xml** file. When I launch it on eclipse emulator, It works fine. But if I launch it on my ***samsung galaxy star*** devices, the camera will start in landscape mode.
If I used the following code after cameraPreview.open() then it works fine in ***samsung galaxy star*** but then it open in landscape mode in emulator.

```
cameraPreview.setDisplayOrientation(90)
```

How to fix this issue so that the camera will launch on both or any devices in portrait mode?

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camera"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.camera.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="CameraFrameMainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="CameraActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib yes, I have done that....

Comment: oh sorry. I missed that.

Comment: Maybe you can first check the width and height, and then decide if setDisplayOrientation() is needed?

Comment: I think [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) may help you. it handles getting the rotation to then set the rotation

Comment: Just in case you missed something, can you paste your Manifest file please.

Comment: @HpTerm I have pasted my manifest in my question.

Comment: @CrazyLearner I confirm I don't see any mistake in you manifest.